# sub facet in SOLR

Tags: java, solr, lucene, facet

I have following scenario:

```
{
    name: abc,
    legalAccount{
                    name:la1,
                    portAccount{
                                {
                                    paname:pa1,
                                    normalAccount{
                                                    accName:acc1,
                                                    balance:1000
                                                 }
                                }
                    },
                    portAccount{
                                    paname:pa2,
                                    normalAccount{
                                                    accName:acc1,
                                                    balance:2000
                                                 }
                                }
                    }               
    },
    legalAccount{
                    name:la2
                    portAccount{
                                    paname:pa4,
                                    normalAccount{
                                                    accName:acc1,
                                                    balance:100
                                                 }
                                }
                    }
                    portAccount{
                                    paname:pa5,
                                    normalAccount{
                                                    accName:acc1,
                                                    balance:200
                                                 }
                                }
                    }                   
    },
    name: efg
    ..and so on..
}
```

I need to get name , legalAccountname , sum of balance under legalAccountname ,portAccount and sum of balance for the portAccount.
I am using 4.8 version of SOLR and can't upgrade.
I need something like mentioned below but a more optimal output is welcome as the below data is redundant:

```
abc la1 3000 pa1 1000
abc la1 3000 pa2 2000
abc la2 300 pa4 100
abc la2 300 pa5 200
```

Schema details are as follow:

```
<field indexed="true" stored="true" type="string" name="name"/>//abc
<field indexed="true" stored="true" type="string" name="legalaccName"/>//la1
<field indexed="true" stored="true" type="string" name="portaccName"/>//pa1
<field indexed="true" stored="true" type="string" name="normalaccName"/>//acc1
<field indexed="true" stored="true" type="Double" name="Balance" />balance
```

Comment: What does your schema look like?

Comment: Schema details updated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old question. Key there is [sub-facet](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/json-facet-api.html), json facet works well.